# Changing current math mode (e.g. inline to display)

Tags: latex, auctex

Is there a built-in or at least ready-made way to change which math mode I'm in? For example if I'm writing in inline math mode (which in my case would mean my cursor is between single dollar signs) and I want to switch to display math mode (which in my case would mean said dollar signs get changed to `\begin{displaymath}` and `\end{displaymath}`), I'd like to be able to do so with some quick keystrokes.

I'm thinking about something akin to the C-u C-c C-e command. Perhaps I could make dollar signs count as an 'environment'?

If there's not a built-in or ready-made way, don't worry about posting a solution. I'll try to figure it out myself. You can post one if you want though, in case I fail.

Thanks emacs-ers.

Comment: You have probably seen in but I don't know the difference between $ and displaymath environment? Could you explain why you want such a feature? It might help in providing the answer.

Comment: Synatically, the difference is text between single dollar signs versus text between '\begin{displaymath}' and '\end{displaymath}'. This amounts to how the given text is rendered upon compilation. OK?